# Operators on the family of all subsets of a topological space that maybe generates a base for these family.

Tags: general-topology

I will try to do at least something of my first question.

Given a topological space $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, we define two operators on $2^X = \{ A : A \subseteq X \}$ as follows. For $\alpha \subseteq 2^X$ and $M\in 2^X$, define

1. $M\in\tilde{\alpha} \;\Leftrightarrow\; \exists L\in\alpha: \overline{L}\cap \overline{M}\ne\emptyset.$
2. $M\in\tilde{\alpha} \;\Leftrightarrow\;
   \exists L\in\alpha: L\cap M\ne\emptyset.$

I think the operators define closed bases for two topologies on $2^X$, and that the first operator defines a topology which is a refinement of the second. That is, 
$\{\beta\in 2^X|\exists \alpha\in\ 2^X:\beta=\tilde{\alpha}\}$ is a base for a topology given by a set of all closed sets in $2^X$.

([See also on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133030/defining-a-topology-in-the-power-set/179544#179544))

Comment: (1) What do you mean by $2^X$? (I think you might mean the family of all subsets of $X$, but for _hyperspaces_ $2^X$ is more commonly used to denote the family of closed subsets of the space $X$.) (2) Have you verified that these operators define a closure operator on $2^X$? It seems to me that they might both fail to satisfy $\overline{ \overline{\alpha} } = \overline{\alpha}$.

Comment: @Arthur Fischer: I mean the set of all subsets and believe I can prove the two topologies, but are to rusty to trust in only my own opinion. I could answer my own question but would very much appreciate to see a second opinion first.

Comment: I made some substantial changes to the phrasing of this question, also incorporating the content of your above comment. Please check it over to ensure I didn't entirely alter the meaning of your question.

Comment: You are right. It holds that $\overline{\underset{i}\bigcap \alpha_i}\subseteq\underset{i}\bigcap \overline{\alpha_i}$ when $M\in\overline{\alpha} \Leftrightarrow
\exists L\in\alpha: \overline{L}\cap \overline{M}\ne\emptyset$ but no more. Could the idea be used for a base of closed sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these proposed operators are "closure operators" on $\mathcal{P} ( X ) = 2^X$. Recall that given a set $Y$, a mapping $\operatorname{cl} : \mathcal{P}(Y) \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ is the closure operator of a topology on $Y$ if and only if it satisfies the [Kuratowski closure axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_closure_axioms):

1. $\operatorname{cl} ( \varnothing ) = \varnothing$;
2. $A \subseteq \operatorname{cl} ( A )$;
3. $\operatorname{cl} ( A \cup B ) = \operatorname{cl} ( A ) \cup \operatorname{cl} ( B )$; and
4. $\operatorname{cl} ( \operatorname{cl} ( A ) ) = \operatorname{cl} ( A )$.

The proposed operators both fail (2) and usually both fail (4).

- For (2), note that $\varnothing \notin \overline{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \subseteq \mathcal{P} ( X )$, so in particular $\{ \varnothing \} \not\subseteq \overline{\{ \varnothing \}}$. (This holds for both proposed operators.) If you instead consider your $2^X$ to be the family of *nonempty* subsets of $X$ this problem can be removed, so is in some sense inessential.
- (4) is a more substantial problem. Note that if $\tau$ is the discrete topology on the set $X$, then the two proposed closure operators coincide. Considering $X = \{ 0 , 1 \}$ with the discrete topology $\tau = \{ \varnothing , \{ 0 \} , \{ 1 \} , \{ 0 , 1 \} \}$, it is easy to calculate $\overline{ \{\,\{ 0 \}\,\} } = \{\,\{ 0 \} , \{ 0 , 1 \}\,\}$, and $\overline{\{\,\{0\},\{0,1\}\,\}} = \{\,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\,\}$, so $\overline{ \overline{ \{\,\{0\}\,\} } } \neq \overline{ \{\,\{0\}\,\} }$.

  More generally, given any topological space $X$, if $\alpha \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$  contains a nonempty element, then $X \in \overline{ \alpha }$, and it follows that $\overline{ \overline{ \alpha } } = \{ A \subseteq X : A \neq \varnothing \}$. (Again, this holds for both proposed operators.)